Github Actions: Run script only if ALL changed files in PR are in a single directory
I can't seem to find documentation specifying how to make sure that the filter only passes if ALL of the files in the PR follow a certain rule rather than if ANY of the files pass a certain rule.
For example, the following code will trigger if ANY of the files are under [folder], but I'd like it to trigger if ALL of the files are under [folder].
on:
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - "[folder]/**"

Refs: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#patterns-to-match-file-paths
Similar question, but asks about any instead of all: How to run GitHub Actions workflow only if the pushed files are in a specific folder

This path trigger on the workflow config check if at least one file on the directory has been updated. If you want to do something more specific, you'll need to use an action in a specific job, like this one. This thread might give some insights.
